# How to dynamically load js script with json between the script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have difficulty to understand how to dynamically load the following script when a button is pressed. The reason for doing so its because the symbol property in the json will be changing and having this script loaded n times on the pages becomes very slow.

Here is the snippet which I want to load:

```
 <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
                <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
                {
                "width": "100%",
                "height": 410,
                "symbol": "BTCUSD",
                "locale": "en",
                "interval": "1D"
                }
                </script>
                </div>
```

Basically a function _loadWidget() with property of symbol needs to be sed which adds this to the DOM with it's properties.

Comment: 1. You need an api endpoint to call that will answer you with your json data. 2. You need a button 3. You need a listener on your button that will use `fetch` method to get data from your endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do but does this give you some guidance?

```
 <button id="myButton" type="submit">Press Me</button>


 <script>

    $("#myButton").click(function(){

        console.log("Do Something")

    })

 </script>
```

When you press the button do something? If this isn't for your question I'll delete the answer just tell me :)